# Neo4j cyper query: How to get unique nodes for two depth with their depth value

Tags: neo4j

I am using Cyper query in neo4j

My requirement is,
   need to get two level unique(friends) and their shortest depth value.

Graph looks like,

```
a-[:frnd]->b, b-[:frnd]->a
b-[:frnd]->c, c-[:frnd]->b
c-[:frnd]->d, d-[:frnd]->c

a-[:frnd]->c, c-[:frnd]->a
```

I tried as,

```
    START n=node(8) match p=n-[:frnd*1..2]->(x)  return x.email, length(p)
```

My output is,

```
b        1  <--length(p)    
a        2
c        2
c        1
d        2
a        2    and so on.
```

My required output,

My parent node(a) should not not be listed.

I need only (c) with shortest length 1

c with 2 should not be repeated.

Pls help me to solve this,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDITED. Finding `n` via `START n=node(8)` causes problems with other variables later on. So, below we find `n` in the `MATCH` statement.)

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((n {email:"a"})-[:frnd*..2]->(x))
WHERE n <> x AND length(p) > 0
RETURN  x.email, length(p)
ORDER BY length(p)
LIMIT 1
```

If there are multiple "closest friends", this returns one of them.

Also, the `shortestPath()` function does not support a minimal path length -- so "*1..2" had be become "*..2", and the WHERE clause needed to specify `length(p) > 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. one probs
START n = node(8)
MATCH p = shortestPath((n)-[:frnd*..2]->(x)) throws error as Unknown identifier `x`.
Unknown identifier `p`.
START n = node(8)
MATCH p = ((n)-[:frnd*..2]->(x))
query is executing,
when we use shortestPath, it throughing error,
how to fix it

Comment: See the addition to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I have added all the condition, but it throws error as unknown identifier x, i think shortestPath will work only when we know both the end of node. i am not sure

Comment: For some reason, my edits to my answer are gone. Are you sure you have a node with ID of 8 -- that was copied from your question. If it does not exist, remove the `START` line, and change `(n)` to `(n {email:"a"})` in the `MATCH` line.

Comment: OK, see my re-edited answer. The `START` statement is causing this issue for some reason.